# map method with mutated iterator

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have an array of objects I want to iterate through with map-

```
object_array.map {|o| o.dostuff }
```

But I want o iterator to be a string representation of the object, so I have to do something like this-

```
object_array.map do |o|
  o = o.to_s
  o.dostringstuff
end
```

Is there any way to do it in one line? (intrepreter doesn't accept this)

```
object_array.map {|o.to_s| o.dostringstuff }
```

Comment: Why do you prefer the selected answer, which requires one pass though the array and one pass through the mapped array, and creates a temporary array,  to @Draco's answer, which requires a single pass and does not create a temporary array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not chain `map`s, especially with a [shorthand syntax via `Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc)?

```
object_array.map(&:to_s).map(&:dostringstuff)
```

Comment: Haven't thought about it.
It does solve it in one line but it iterates twice instead of only once.

Comment: @Akra Yes, it does, but since your data needs conversion anyway, no matter what you're going to be doing multiple operations on each element. The question is when.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with:

```
object_array.map{|o| o.to_s.dostringstuff }
```

?

Comment: Assume I have to do several string related operations, so it will result in something in the sort of o.to_s[o.to_s.index(someindex)..o.to_s.rindex(otherindex)] if s.to_s.match(someexpression)

Comment: @Akra Then your data is wrong; you should be mapping it once it's the way you want it since the mapping is the "dominant" operation, and data conversion is just auxiliary work so you can do what you actually want to it.

Comment: Then `object_array.map(&:to_s)` first as @BrightOne suggested

Comment: Akra, you question is clear. Your comment pertains to a different question. This answer is the most direct and economical way to obtain the desired result. If you have another question, submit it separately.